# How can I change one material texture in an array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I change one material in an array?

I've imported a Daz figure into unity, all of the materials are stored in an array for the figure.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the array]

I'm trying to change the texture of the Irises with the click of a button.

The code below does change the material but only on the first material in the array. I've attempted to alter the code to change the Irises, but I have been unable to.

```
{
//Component
private Renderer _rendereyes;

//Game Object
public GameObject eyes;

//etc
public Object[] texEyes;
public int texID;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //Get Component
    _rendereyes = eyes.GetComponent<Renderer>();

    //Change eye tex
    string texPath = "Textures";
    texEyes = Resources.LoadAll(texPath, typeof(Texture2D));
}

public void SetEyeTexture()
{
    if (texID < texEyes.Length - 1)
    {
        texID++;
    }
    else
    {
        texID = 0;
    }
    _rendereyes.material.SetTexture("_DiffuseMap",(Texture2D)texEyes[texID]);
}
```

Here is the 2nd iteration of the code which is my attempt to alter the Irises texture.

```
{
//Component
private Renderer[] _rendereyes;

//Game Object
public GameObject eyes;

//etc
public Object[] texEyes;
public int texID;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //Get Component
    _rendereyes = eyes.GetComponent<Renderer[]>();

    //Change eye tex
    string texPath = "Textures";
    texEyes = Resources.LoadAll(texPath, typeof(Texture2D));
}

public void SetEyeTexture()
{
    if (texID < texEyes.Length - 1)
    {
        texID++;
    }
    else
    {
        texID = 0;
    }
    _rendereyes[15].material.SetTexture("_DiffuseMap",(Texture2D)texEyes[texID]);
}
```

What is the best way to change the Irises texture?

Comment: nothing in your code is called `Materials` so how is your screenshot related to the code?

Comment: Also why not rather be specific and do `public Texture2D[] texEyes;` and `texEyes = Resources.LoadAll<Texture2D>(texPath);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in general avoid using `Resources` at all. (See [Best practices -> Resources](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7))

> **Don't use it!**

---

Then if you use it and in general I would be more specific and do

```
public Texture2D[] texEyes;
```

and then

```
texEyes = Resources.LoadAll<Texture2D>(texPath);
```

or rather simply drag and drop them into the slots via the Inspector

---

And finally

```
GetComponent<Renderer[]>
```

makes no sense. You always want to either get a single component or use `GetComponents`.

However, it sounds like you actually have only one single object with one single `Renderer` and want to stick to

```
_rendereyes = eyes.GetComponent<Renderer>();
```

or directly make it

```
[SerializeField] private Renderer _rendereyes;
```

and drag the object into the slot in the Inspector.

And then rather access the according index from [`Renderer.materials`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html).

And then you have a little logical mistake in your `SetEyeTexture` method.

You do

```
if (texID < texEyes.Length - 1)
{
    texID++;
}
```

which might result in `texID = texEyes.Length` which will be out o bounds since in `c#` all indices go from `0` to `array.Length - 1`.

Your code should rather look like

```
public void SetEyeTexture()
{
    // Simple modulo trick to get a wrap around index
    texID = (++texID) % texEyes.Length;
    
    // Note that according to your screenshot the Material "Irises" is at index 14 not 15!
    _rendereyes.materials[14].SetTexture("_DiffuseMap", texEyes[texID]);
}
```